# Issue with calculated column

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I have a calculated column `CRM ID` with simple formula `=CONCATENATE("CRM")&ID`. The formula concatenates ID field with string `CRM`.

The issue is: Sometimes when user update list records, the `CRM ID` field doesn't show ID.It shows only CRM string. This issue is intermittent.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ID is unreliable when using a calculated column, which is why it doesn't appear in the options as a column to use when building a formula. I used a similar technique before and experienced the same issues as you.

What I did was convert it to an on creation workflow to set the field value instead. This is much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ID field, when I tried retrieving the ID value in ItemAdding Event.The ID Field will be updated only after the item is added to the List. So Please try creating "CRM ID" as string field and update it in ItemAdded event, instead using calculated formula.

Answer (score 0):

ID is not unreliable, it does what it is programmed for.

Calculated Formulas are processed **before** a new Item is written to the database where it gets an ID.

That is why **ID is empty for New items** but has the correct ID when an Item is changed/updated.

If you need ID in a Formula you have to trigger that update for newly created items, simplest is to create a Workflow triggered on New Item which writes the ID value to a extra column MyID.
The Workflow runs after the item is written to the database so picks up the correct ID value.

If you do not want an extra column you can also use a Workflow to overwrite any other field with the existing value, this will trigger an Item update as well.

Note: if you only want to use ID in a **View**, you can also get it with some JavaScript in a Calculated Column.
http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/4 has a detailed explanation.