# Calculated value field not the correct value in the main list view column

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

so I want to make a counter in my list that stars from a custom number.

In the custom form I added a calculated value called CustomID and calculated the value for that field with: ID + 100
When I create a new item in a list CustomID is the right value when I look at that item, but when i look at the whole list all items in column CustomID has value 100.
What can i do so the column match the items CustomID value.

Comment: Using ID in a calculated column is bad practice.

Comment: So how would you do it?

Comment: you can't use ID in calculated field's formula because ID is generated while adding. The ID gets generated once item is successfully added into list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate: [Issue with calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135429/issue-with-calculated-column)

ID is 0 for newly created items because it gets its value from the database **after** the Formulas in Calculated Columns are evaluated.

The only way to use ID in a Formula is to start a Workflow on Item creation, read the ID (the Workflow is executed after the item is created) and write the value to your Column *CustomID* (and do the +100 at the same time), so change your column from Calculated to Number